# Can you use Vimeo API to set up a "buy now" type button on your website?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

The company I work for uses Vimeo to sell some webinars they produce, and right now we have a page on the site users go to to view them. But in order to purchase the video, they have to click on the small "Rent" button on the video player.

I'm wondering if there is a way to utilize the Vimeo API, to create our own, bigger and better "Buy Now" type button, that when clicked, starts the purchase process for a specific video on Vimeo.

I've found this page about Vimeo's On Demand API, but I'm not a backend developer, so I don't really understand how API's work.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/features/ondemandvideo

I'm not really asking how to do this, although I'd love to know, but if someone has done this before or knows that it's possible, please let me now and I can find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to create your own "Buy Now" button. You could create a button that links back to the On Demand page on Vimeo, however.

It's worth noting that when you embed a VOD video, the Player will have a "Buy" or "Rent" button that will prompt the user to log in or enter/confirm payment.

Comment: Thanks Tommy - appreciate the answer. That's kind of what I figured.

Comment: Happy to help you out!